# tengo este error "ContextCompat no existe en el contexto actual" y un "PackageManager no contiene definición PERMISSION_GRANTED"

Tags: c#, xamarin, app

Hola cuando creo el método sale error "ContextCompat no existe en el contexto actual" y un "PackageManager no contiene definición PERMISSION_GRANTED" .. saben si debo agregar alguna directiva en especial. Gracias

METODO

```
 private void CheckSMSStatePermission()
{

    int PermissionCheck = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.SendSms);
    if (PermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Activity,  "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.SendSms }, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

CÓDIGO COMPLETO

```
 private void MBtnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (mTxtInstitucion.Text.Equals("")|| mTxtCiudad.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "has dejado Institución o Ciudad vacia", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }

        else
        {


            try
            {
                //Configurando el cliente SMTP
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com", "jwspvnzutniimmmmm")
                };
                //Preparando archivo adjunto
                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
                var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                var path = Uri.FromFile(File);


                //Enviando correo
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com")
                };
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("ingsisacontreras@gmail.com"));
                mail.Subject = "Solicitud Autorizacion Medica " + mTxtNombre + " " + mTxtApellido + "" + mTxtCedula;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = "Hola Solicito por favor autorizar procedimiento, adjunto anexo solicitud Medica especificaciones el nombre de la Institución es  " + mTxtInstitucion.Text +
                " , ciudad " + mTxtCiudad.Text + " ,Nombre de usuario " + mTxtNombre + " " + mTxtApellido + " y Cedula " + mTxtCedula +
                " " + "Gracias por su atención"
                ;
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(File.Path));
                client.Send(mail);
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNota).Text = MSJTEnvioExitoso;
                Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCiudad).Text = "";
                textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoInstitucion).Text = "";

                CheckSMSStatePermission();
                SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("57301111111", null,
                "Hello from Xamarin.Android", null, null);
                var smsUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:57301111111");
                var smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto, smsUri);
                smsIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", "Hello from Xamarin.Android");
                StartActivity(smsIntent);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Mensaje Fallido"+ex, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }



    private void CheckSMSStatePermission()
    {

        int PermissionCheck = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.SendSms);
        if (PermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity,  "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.SendSms }, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el error de los permisos debes agregar este permiso:

```
Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted
```

Comment: Hola ingreso como permiso y salen los mimos errores, por favor ejemplo para validar si los estoy dando bien

Comment: @AndrésFelipeContrerasMuñoz puedes añadir tus permisos?

Comment: `using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using Java.IO;
using Android.Provider;
using System.IO;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;`

Comment: no me refiero a los using, si no a los permisos de la aplicación. Puedes verlos en--> propiedades de tu proyecto -->en Android Manifest

Comment: que pena doy nuevo ..

Comment: "android.permission.INTERNET" />
"android.permission.CAMERA" />
"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAG" />
"android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
"android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
"android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
"android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
"PERMISSION_GRANTED" />
"android.hardware.telephony"/>) `

Comment: @AndrésFelipeContrerasMuñoz pues a estos permisos tienes que añadir el que te puse en la respuesta: Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted

Comment: hola he ralizado todo lo que me has informado, pero en la accion THIS sale mensaje No se puede Convertir de 'LoginSystem.Autorizacion' a 'Android.Content.Contex' codigo  String permission = Android.Manifest.Permission.SendSms;
                    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.SendSms)
                        != Permission.Granted)
                    {
                        Android.Support.V4.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[]
                                      {permission}, 1);

                    }